# Cant throw base class exception from dervied class

Tags: c++, exception

I wrote a code where instead of throwing derived class exception i threw base class exception from my derived class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
  class BaseException {};
  class DerivedException : public BaseException {};
  virtual void f() throw(DerivedException) {
    throw DerivedException();
  }
  virtual void g() throw(BaseException) {
    throw BaseException();
  }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  void f() throw (BaseException) 
  {
    throw BaseException();
  }
  virtual void g() throw (BaseException)
 {
    throw DerivedException();
  }
};

int main()
{
    Derived D;

    return 0;
}
```

http://codepad.org/xMdNAeVE

It fails to compile and says

```
Line 18: error: looser throw specifier for 'virtual void Derived::f() throw (Base::BaseException)'
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

I searched on net and it seems like derived class violates the contract that has been made in base class .

My doubt is that base class made a contract for derived class object however , i am using base class , so where is the contract broken .

Comment: I would suggest removing the exception specifier. This feature never really took on, and has been deprecated in C++11.

Comment: You didn't write this code. It comes from [Thinking in C++ Vol 2](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/c++_practical_programming/c++_practical_programming_032.html) and is **supposed to fail!**.

Comment: The page that Captain Obvlious links to fully answers this question.

Comment: yes captain , it comes from thinking in c++ but i modified it for sending only base class exception from derived class as that was my doubt . I had no intention of taking credit of author but just to learn .. sorry if it hurt ur feelings

Comment: @MAG The **only** thing you changed was the exception specification of `g()`. You claimed it as your own, didn't attribute the original source and didn't indicate the changes. The answer is on the webpage I linked and had you paid attention you would have known what the problem is prior to making the change and posting it as a question.

Comment: @captain .. it was never my intention to claim it my own , but giving all those details , in my opinion,  would have taken the conversation in a wrong direction .. i now feel that people have more interest in difference with original code than the question asked .. its obvious that i must have not understood something that i had posted here . may be knowing differences  helps , may be it wont but i think i should have posted  .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
virtual void Base::f() throw(DerivedException)
```

and

```
void Derived::f() throw(BaseException)
```

You basically promised that `anyBase.f` would throw a `DerivedException` (more specialized) exception. Then in your `Derived class` you are trying to "relax" that promise, telling you would throw a more generic `BaseException`. When you derive one class from another you cannot do that. Either change the first to `throw(BaseException)` or the second to `throw(DerivedException)`. you can even do both, because then the `Derived` class would be **restricting** the contract made by the `Base` class, and **that** is allowed.